# Simple calculator works in Python 2 but not 3

Tags: python-3.x, calculator

This calculator works in Python 2:

```
print ("First calculator!")

print ("")

firstnum=input ("Insert the first number: ")
print ("")
print ("Available operations:\n 1:Addition\n 2:Subtraction\n 3:Multiplication\n 4:Division\n")
operation=input ("Insert the number of operation: ")
if int(operation) >4:
        print ("You mistyped")
        exit(0)
print ("")
secondnum=input ("Insert the second number: ")

if operation == 1:
    print ("The result is:", firstnum+secondnum)
if operation == 2:
    print ("The result is:", firstnum-secondnum)
if operation == 3:
    print ("The result is:", firstnum*secondnum)
if operation == 4:
    print ("The result is:", firstnum/secondnum)
```

But in Python 3 the script does nothing after accepting input.

--UPDATE--

After fixing thanks the help of @moses-koledoye, I'll post the final source code, it could be help for some other newbie.

```
print ("First calculator!")
print ("")

firstnum=input ("Insert the first number: ")
print ("")
print ("Available operations:\n 1:Addition\n 2:Subtraction\n 3:Multiplication\n 4:Division\n")
operation=input ("Insert the number of operation: ")
if int(operation) >4:
        print ("You mistyped")
        exit(0)
print ("")
secondnum=input ("Insert the second number: ")

firstnum=int(firstnum)
secondnum=int(secondnum)

print ("")
if operation == "1":
    print ("The result is:", firstnum+secondnum)
elif operation == "2":
    print ("The result is:", firstnum-secondnum)
elif operation == "3":
    print ("The result is:", firstnum*secondnum)
elif operation == "4":
    print ("The result is:", firstnum/secondnum)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing strings with integers:

```
if operation == 1 # '1' == 1
```

will always be `False`, so none of the `if` blocks is executed.

Do a *string-string* comparison instead:

```
if operation == '1'
```

---

And when the `if` block conditions are fixed, others bugs will show up:

```
firstnum + secondnum
```

This will concat your strings and not perform a numerical operation as you intend, while operation `-`, `*` and `/` will raise `TypeError`. You should *cast* your operands, *firstnum* and *secondnum* to the appropriate type: `float` or `int`.

---

Besides, you could also chain all the `if` clauses into one `if-elif` clause